# Windows Search wont start (Error 1053)

Tags: windows, windows-10, services

**Windows 10**

"The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion."
It's already set on Automatic Delayed Start, it was shown immediately after clicking Start.
Please, don't suggest things like install NET Framework 1.1 SP1, or registry entry because it isn't set on Automatic Delayed Start, or as some MS person suggested go to services and click start.

There is no feature in remove add windows compoments with name "Windows Search", so don't suggest me that at all.

Comment: [See if this fix solves it](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2484025)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was just needed to get into Windows Indexing in Control Panel, and then click scan again, after a minute, Windows Indexing was get start, and after every boot it's working alright.