# Service does not start

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, search

I cannot start Windows 8.1 search service.

The error I get:

> Windows could not start search service on local computer. Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.

I tried to check turn on or off Windows features, but there is no Windows search.

Registry manipulation: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\ServicesPipeTimeout` does not change anything.

`Sfc /scannow` did not help.

EDIT:
after suggested registry fix service is now started, but outlook is not searching. 
https://rickliev.wordpress.com/2013/06/28/outlook-2013-search-not-working/ did not helped. Same error: we could not find what you were looking for.

Comment: One of these fixes ought to help [Fix Windows Search Error 1053 "Service did not respond"](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/windows-search-service-error-1053-windows-7/)    |    [Windows Search wont start (Error 1053) - Super User](http://superuser.com/questions/959028/windows-search-wont-start-error-1053)

Comment: That helped but did not solved the problem

Comment: May be the search index database has been corrupted, try to rebuild it: Control Panel > Indexing Options > Advanced > Index Settings > Rebuild, to check if it gets to work again.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, nothing I did would allow the Windows Search service to start and I thus I had no search capability.

Eventually I renamed (on a Windows 10 PC):

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\search\data
```

to

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\search\datax
```

The service immediately restarted, created a new data directory, and rebuilt the indexes. I assume something corrupted was screwing things up.